# Add Facebook App to Django to get permissions on Facebook pages

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, django-facebook

There are some Facebook pages on which i want to post on behalf of Page Admin.I want something like this:

1. Facebook page admin login using Facebook account and authenticates by clicking on button
2. I captures all the rights(page_access_token and page_ID) to publish content in his facebook page
3. Some user who comes to my site can publish his message on respective facebook page.

The problem is with First and Second point, I have made an Facebook App for authentication part, but how do i integrate it with Django. I am able to post on particular facebook page when i have page_access_token and page_ID using [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/) .

Code below publish the feed on facebook page.

```
import facebook
oauth_access_token = "page_access_token"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="Hello, world")
```

Its more of a Django App then Facebook app.Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide that describes the first two steps quite well I think. Links to that site are not allowed though, I have no idea why. Let me just say that searching for "Post to Facebook on Behalf of Your User with Python/Django" on Google might possibly help.